How can I prevent my Dialogflow voicebot from treating long responses as fallback intents?
I have built a chatbot using Dialogflow, and I am trying to integrate this chatbot with Dialogflow Phone Gateway. The chatbot works well when I try it with the Web Demo. However, whenever I respond to the chatbot with long responses, it recognizes them as fallback intents, and the conversation does not continue. How can I prevent my Dialogflow voicebot from treating long responses as fallback intents?
Please help me....
Thank you
I tried to maximize the timeout duration at the Cloud run setting. But it does not work.
I also tried to edit the fulfillment setting but as I am not using webhook, I cannot solve the problem with this method.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
